# Can we stop async function with a while inside?

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await

Im new to angular(and codding) and i was wondering if its possible to start adding values after some time (with setTimeout) to a variable once i trigger in html , and then,  stop the process clicking another button. 
Here is the html:

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <button (click)="addingNumber(5000)">Start adding Number</button>
  </span>
  <span>
    <button (click)="stopAddingNumber()">Stop Adding Number</button>
  </span>
</div>
<div>{{actualNumber}}</div>
```

and here is the Ts im trying :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-number-add',
  templateUrl: './number-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./number-add.component.css']
})
export class NumberAdd implements OnInit {

  actualNumber = 0;
  countActive: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  waitTime(awaitTime: number) {
    return new Promise(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.actualNumber += 1;
      }, awaitTime);
    });
  }

  async addingNumber(time: number) {
    this.countActive = true;
    while (this.countActive) {
      await this.waitTime(time);
    }
  }

  stopAddingNumber() {
    this.countActive = false;
  }
}
```

When i try this code,it justs prints 1 and "stops" there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if i have understood your problem, how about using setInterval and clearInterval instead. here is a code expample, i am not sure if it will run normally.

```
export class NumberAdd implements OnInit {

  actualNumber = 0;
  countActive: boolean;
  interval = null;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addingNumber(time: number) {
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
    }

    interval = setInterval(() {
        this.actualNumber += 1;
    }, time);
  }

  stopAddingNumber() {
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    interval = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked nicely , thanks! Got messed up thinking i had to fallow the async/await path. The async can be removed.

Comment: There are four problems with this code: 1) `interval` is not a class member, but a `var`. 2) `addingNumber` is not `async` and does not need to be declared as `async`. 3) `addingNumber` doesn't check if an interval is already queued, allowing additional intervals to be queued which will then be unclearable. 4) `stoppAddingNumber` does not set `interval` to a falsy state, like `null`.

Comment: Yes, it has problems. code has been redited, hope it is ok now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `async/await` to do what you are trying to do. Using `setInterval` and `clearInterval` will give you the desired effect.

```
actualNumber = 0;
interval = null;

addingNumber(time: number) {
    if (this.interval === null) {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.actualNumber++, time);
    }
}

stopAddingNumber() {
    if (this.interval !== null) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.interval = null;
    }
}
```